# Jquery search for image

Tags: jquery, web-scraping

Hy,

My question is verry simple, but i can't get grip on the answer.

I'm making an addon for chrome, that search for an image, and when that image is found on the page, it will do some stuff.

I first had this piece of code:

```
if($('img[src="http://cdn2.tribalwars.net/graphic/unit/att.png?169e1"]').length > 0){
```

And that worked just fine. But today it didn't work. and i know why. Because after the.png comes an random code. because today it is ibdd4.

So how can i search for the image without the ?random code
Because i don't need that random code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the '`startswith`' selector:

```
jQuery('img[src^="http://cdn2.tribalwars.net/graphic/unit/att.png"]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. I'll accept the answer in 11 minuts ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Change it from "equals" to "starts with" in order to ignore the code:

```
if($('img[src^="http://cdn2.tribalwars.net/graphic/unit/att.png?169e1"]').length > 0)
```